# Divide words into syllables in Visual

Tags: prolog

Help me please. I wrote a program in Visual Prolog that divides words into syllables. The last predicate I have to release is dividing word with free syllable. I have  a predicate with vocal-consonant vocal for words excluding smth like name, blame, fine etc. So, my program divides name as na-me, which is wrong solution. When I added needed divide predicate, the program ignored it. How can I write two similar predicates for open and closed syllables?
Thank you.

```
 DOMAINS
letter = char
word_ = letter*

PREDICATES
    divide(word_,word_,word_,word_)
    vocal(letter)
    unvocal(letter)
    consonant(letter)
    string_word(string,word_)
    append(word_,word_,word_)

CLAUSES
    divide(Start,[T1,T2,T3|Rest],D,[_|Rest]):-
        vocal(T1),consonant(T2),unvocal(T3),
        append(Start,[T1,T2,T3],D).
    divide(Start,[T1,T2|Rest],D1,[T2|Rest]):-
        vocal(T1),vocal(T2),
        append(Start,[T1],D1).
    divide(Start,[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5|Rest],D1,[T3,T4,T5|Rest]):-
        vocal(T1),consonant(T2), consonant(T3), consonant(T4),vocal(T5),
        append(Start,[T1,T2],D1).    
    divide(Start,[T1,T2,T3|Rest],D1,[T2,T3|Rest]):-
        vocal(T1),consonant(T2),vocal(T3),
        append(Start,[T1],D1).
    divide(Start,[T1,T2,T3,T4|Rest],D1,[T3,T4|Rest]):-
        vocal(T1),consonant(T2),consonant(T3),vocal(T4),
        append(Start,[T1,T2],D1).
    divide(Start,[T1|Rest],D1,D2):-
        append(Start,[T1],S),
        divide(S,Rest,D1,D2).

    unvocal('e').
    vocal('a'). vocal('e'). vocal('i').
    vocal('o'). vocal('u'). vocal('y').

    consonant(B):-
        not(vocal(B),unvocal(B)).

    string_word("",[]):-!.
    string_word(Str,[H|T]):-
        bound(Str),frontchar(Str,H,S),string_word(S,T).
    string_word(Str,[H|T]):-
        free(Str),bound(H),string_word(S,T),frontchar(Str,H,S).
    append([],L,L):-!.
    append([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]):-
        append(L1,L2,L3).


GOAL
            write("Write a multi-syllable word: "),
            readln(S),nl,
            string_word(S,Word),
            divide([],Word,Part1,Part2),
            string_word(Syllable1,Part1),
            string_word(Syllable2,Part2),
            write("Division: ",Syllable1,"-",Syllable2),nl,
        fail.
```

Comment: Yes, I mean vowel and a clause for predicate (english isn't my mother language, so I can make mistakes). This code works, it's ok.

Comment: I added a clause for closed syllable at the top, look at the code. I hoped that it will solve my problem but it didn't. Wrote a special predicate unvocal just for 'e' in the end of word and can't understand, what's wrong